# SPSS computing pairwise comparisons after repeated measures ANCOVA, standard deviation question

Tags: spss, standard-deviation, standard-error

I am reporting standard deviations for pairwise comparisons of adjusted marginal means. SPSS gives me the standard error that I can convert, but I am unsure if SPSS uses the equivalent of N or N-1 to obtain p-values in pairwise calculations for this situation.
I was unable to find algorithm details for this specific case, and of course I wish to report the correct standard deviation for the reported test values. Does anyone know off the top of their head what SPSS is doing in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it was a malformed question. However two things will be useful if someone in the future has a similar issue.

First, SPSS by default does use N-1 in standard deviation calculations (in general) and

Second, there is a good reason SPSS does not provide standard deviations for this situation. Because the estimated marginal means are not from observations, but rather collapse information as a model-based estimate, you use standard error as the uncertainty statistic. There is no dispersion of a set of values.